# how do i link an int to a string inside a string array java

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

im writing a program where I have to have the computer randomly choose 1 of 10 objects that i have written down as a string array... im using the the math.random function to come up with a number...

```
int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
System.out.println("I'm thinking of an item, I will only choose one of 10...");
```

how do i link that randomly generated int to a string inside a string array with ten different items inside... first time doing java and a pretty big noob, keep failing at this part

```
public static String getElement(int x){ 

    String[] stringArray = new String[10];

        stringArray[0] = "Gold";
        stringArray[1] = "Barnacle";
        stringArray[2] = "Wenches";
        stringArray[3] = "Wooden Leg";
        stringArray[4] = "Davey Jones Locker";
        stringArray[5] = "Keira Knightley";
        stringArray[6] = "Capt. Sparrow's Sword";
        stringArray[7] = "The Black Pearl";
        stringArray[8] = "Davey Jones Heart";
        stringArray[9] = "Diamonds";

    return stringArray[x];
}
```

its pirates of the caribean themed... school work

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you mean when you say "link that randomly generated int to a string inside a string array with ten different items inside"?

Answer (score 3):

With the code you posted, you can just do:

```
int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
System.out.println("I'm thinking of an item, I will only choose one of 10...");
System.out.println(getElement(targetNumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to select one of the Strings. This is done by addressing the String array's index. Target number will generate that index, so what you do is `stringArray[targetNumber]`. This will return the String at the designated index.

If targetNumber is `3`, "Wooden leg" will be selected.

Try it with `System.out.println(getElement(targetNumber));`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringArray[targetNumber]` to get the string "pointed to" by the random number.